# TextView with mixed languages

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left

I have a `TextView` with 2 lines. first line rtl language (let's say hebrew), second line is ltr language (let's say english)

The `View` result is *something like*:

```
       אחת שתיים שלוש
one two three
```

*what i want*: align rtl in that case

```
       אחת שתיים שלוש
          one two three
```

I've tried using [setTextDirection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTextDirection(int)) with [TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG)
but alas the results were the same. Also tried [TEXT_ANY_RTL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL) without success

```
myTextView.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG);
```

if i'm using [TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL) it's working as expected but this is not really a solution because most of the time the `TextView` will contain only one language.

Is this solvable?

--- UPDATE ---

How i'm populating the `TextView`

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(titleText);
int end = titlText.length();
ssb.append("\n").append(otheText);
ssb.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(size), end, ssb.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: Ummm... how are you populating this `TextView`? Are you using `LocaleSpan` or something? IOW, how does a `TextView` know that the text is in one, two, or thirty languages?

Comment: i'm using `SpannableStringBuilder`. i've updated the question. `titleText` and `otherText` may or may not be of the same language.

Comment: i've hoped that `TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG` will do the trick because of the *The first strong directional character determines the paragraph direction* documantation line

Comment: What Java class is the implementation of `titleText` and `otherText`? `String`? If yes, I do not know why or how `TextView` would have those on separate lines with separate RTL/LTR settings. If no, then what are they?

Comment: they are of Class `String`. the separate lines are because i'm also appending `\n`...`ssb.append("\n").append(otheText);`

Comment: Yes, but then I can't explain how `TextView` is deciding to have one line be RTL and the other be LTR. I suppose they could be looking at charsets or something, concluding that you're referring to Unicode characters in the Hebrew range, and deciding to make that be RTL. And since I can't explain how `TextView` is doing any of this, I *really* can't explain how to change that behavior. I'm with Karim: use two `TextView` widgets, and try forcing the text direction on a per-`TextView` basis.

Comment: I've tried 2 `TextView`, unless i have some kind of language detection algorithm, 2 `TextView` will give the exact same result...one will be RTL, the second LTR

Comment: "unless i have some kind of language detection algorithm" -- I'll be surprised if you can avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use two TextViews?

Comment: because the result will be the same. the upper `textView` will have rtl direction and the bottom one will have ltr direction. and also because for my usage the `TextView` has a gradient and to split it to 2 would be a problem. and last because it's really interesting for me why `TEXT_DIRECTION` is not working and how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem using [Character.getDirectionality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getDirectionality(char)).

The first char that is a directional char will signify the `TextView` direction

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static int getTextDirection(String text) {
    final int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        final char c = text.charAt(i);
        final byte directionality = Character.getDirectionality(c);

        if(directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_LEFT_TO_RIGHT){
            return View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR;
        }
        else if(directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT){
            return View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL;
        }
    }

    return View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL;
}
```

and then:

```
textView.setTextDirection(textDirection);
```

I Strongly believe that `TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG` is supposed to do the exact same thing according to the docs. sadly it's not the case.

I'm not accepting my answer in hope that someone will suggest better solution

Answer (score 0):

What About `TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL`

This text direction is using "any-RTL" algorithm. The paragraph direction is RTL if it contains any strong RTL character, otherwise it is LTR if it contains any strong LTR characters. If there are neither, the paragraph direction is the view's resolved layout direction.

Comment: thanks for your answer. sadly i've already tried it and it's not working